# Can I do case sensitive comparison in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql, case-sensitive

I wrote HQL query like this in Hibernate:

```
User userLogIn = (User) entityManager
       .createQuery("from User as u where u.userName=:uname and u.passWord=:pwd")
       .setParameter("uname", user.getUserName())
       .setParameter("pwd", user.getPassWord()).getSingleResult();
```

The above query is working fine but it is not case sensitive. I want to apply case sensitivity to password.

Comment: I think the case sensitivity/insensitivity of the column depends on the type of the column and database vendor. Please tell us what database are you using and how the password column is defined.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that you solve correct problem. For a security reasons you should not save password into DB as plaintext. You should compute hash (eg.  MD5) from password and store it as hexa number into varchar or char(n) field - you don't need to care about case sensitivity because hash for 'a' and 'A' is different.